# XML Marshal Line Endings CRLF

Tags: go

How can I tell xml.Marshal or xml.MarshalIndent to terminate lines in Windows CRLF line endings rather than the LF that it's producing now?

Note: I tried running `strings.Replace(s, "\n", "\r\n", -1)` and `strings.Replace(s, ">\n", ">\r\n", -1)` to transform after the fact but that caused more troubles than it solved. A blanket string replacement won't work.

Comment: I doubt you can. And you should not as CRLF ist wrong anyway.

Comment: >> And you should not as CRLF ist wrong anyway.
That's definitely an opinion and I'm glad you're able to do this but the requirements of the task won't allow it. I really did ask the question I was hoping to have answered.

Comment: Not possible with the encoding/xml package due to the way it emits the newlines on https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/encoding/xml/marshal.go#L964

Comment: Bummer! (But thanks for the definitive link @michael-macdonald.) I hate it when Go doesn't present well because of an arbitrary decision. "Sorry guys, Go's not the right choice for this after all. The designers decided CRLF wasn't something they wanted you to be able to use here."

Comment: CRLF is completely valid for XML per the spec.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/SNYZla8n5jx

Comment: @dave, I'd improve your solution by using a character proxibited in the spec (#x0000, see [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#charsets)): https://play.golang.org/p/HB_A2yW_AnN
(I have also added a CDATA session with two `\r\n` sequences—a possibility for a document to have an almost arbitrary blob of data in this form is often overlooked.)

Comment: @dave, a fixed version which also removes the leading indent: https://play.golang.org/p/GVV899ry2iW

Comment: @kositx, dave Thanks. I had been playing with sentinels but hadn't come up with anything I liked. I do like the "\x00" marker though and it should never appear in data. I'll present this as a not ideal but still reasonable solution and see how it goes.